# Google Big Query - How to assign specific percentage of null values in a column to specific categories?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on a dataset where I am analyzing a ratio between production and development imports. The table looks like this:

```
  Date           Team_id      Outcome
    
2020-10-07           1        Production
2020-10-09           1        Development
2020-10-11           1        Development
2020-10-13           1        Production
2020-10-15           1        Development
2020-10-17           1        Production
   ...
   ...
   ...
2020-06-19           1          NULL
2020-04-21           1          NULL
2020-03-23           1          NULL
2020-01-25           1          NULL
```

As a young company, we only began collecting this information recently. Therefore, all values in this **Outcome** column are Null for dates that took place before we started collecting data on whether an import is done in production or development environment.

For all null values, I would like to make an assumption that 75% of imports were done in Development and 25% of imports were done in Production. (Percentages are random to fit example table above) Therefore, my goal is to convert 75% of all Null values to Developemt category, and 25% of Null values to Production category. Order of which Null values get assigned what values does not matter, it only matters that 75% of them become Development and 25% of them become Production. Considering this, I would like the table from above to look like table below:

```
      Date           Team_id      Outcome
        
    2020-10-07           1        Production
    2020-10-09           1        Development
    2020-10-11           1        Development
    2020-10-13           1        Production
    2020-10-15           1        Development
    2020-10-17           1        Production
       ...
       ...
       ...
    2020-06-19           1        Development
    2020-04-21           1        Production
    2020-03-23           1        Development
    2020-01-25           1        Development
```

Again, based on my target table, it does not matter which values that were null become Development or Production, all that matters is that 75% of null values became Development and 25% of null values became Production.

With my current skills, I know how to assign null values to specific values through CASE statements. What I don’t know is how to assign percentage value to null value to convert desired % of null values to a specific category, such as Production / Development

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following approach:

```
UPDATE dataset.table
SET Outcome = "Development"
WHERE Outcome is null AND RAND() < 0.75
```

Where [RAND()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand) is a function that generates a pseudo-random value of type FLOAT64 in the range of [0, 1), inclusive of 0 and exclusive of 1 but, can be used as a function for sampling, since the order is not important, this function will select random rows, then, in `< 0.75` you are specifying a condition that most likely will update 75% of your data, the bigger the sample the better results (another example of how this may work, Dataprep [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RAND-Function_57344757#example---type-check-functions), but the idea is the same); however, keep in mind that this function provides a uniform distribution, so if your data is skewed, the sample will be skewed.

Then, you can update the data left to "Production" by:

```
UPDATE dataset.table
SET Outcome = "Production"
WHERE Outcome is null
```

NOTE: Please consider that if you run this query directly on your prod table, it will update all the data, so, I first recommend to review this solutions before applying it or you can create another column and then update your values there.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many `nulls` you have.
Pick out the 75% percent position of the null, eg: the day when previous items make 75% and later 25%.

Then issue two update statements, one `where date<T1` and the other `where date>=T1` to update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I understand the first part in which to count how many null values. What I don’t know how to do is to select 75% of all null values and assign them value DEVELOPMENT and select other 25% of null values and assign them PRODUCTION value. Assuming there is no date column in the table above, is there a way to subset data in such a way? I just want to select 75% of random null values per each team in my real table and assign those null values to contain DEVELOPMENT value.

Comment: @Arsik36 see this example: https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/calculate-median/

Comment: Thank you, I am still not clear on how to solve this challenge, but I will continue trying